# return пустой массив

Tags: java, массивы

Как вернуть пустой массив в методе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно возвращать любой тип, то только так:

```
public static <T> T returnArray(T type) {
    return type;
}
```

Работать с методом надо так:

```
System.out.println(((int[])returnArray(new int[0])).length); //0
System.out.println(((char[])returnArray(new char[0])).length); //0
System.out.println(((boolean[][])returnArray(new boolean[0][0])).length); //0
```

Но нужно учитывать, если хотите получить массив, который передали, нужно примерять `(cast)`.
А чтобы проверять `(cast)`, чтобы быть уверенным, к какому типу применяем `(cast)`, нужно

```
System.out.println(returnArray(new int[0]) instanceof int[]); // true
```

Либо делать костыль через `.getClass()`, что в данном случае будет реальный костыль.

А если вам нужно определенный тип возвращать, то тут уж, еще проще:

```
public static int[] returnIntArray() {
    return new int[0];
}
```

**UPD:**

```
public static double[] steigung(double[] d, double r) {
    return d == null || r <= 0 ? null : d.length <= 1 ? new double[0] : d;
}
```

Вывод:

```
System.out.println(steigung(null, 0)); // null
System.out.println(steigung(null, 1)); // null
System.out.println(steigung(new double[0], 0)); // null
System.out.println(steigung(new double[0], 1).length); // 0
System.out.println(steigung(new double[1], 1).length); // 0
System.out.println(steigung(new double[2], 1).length); // 2
```